# std::vector, char *, and C API

Tags: c++, vector, std

I want to use some C API that requires a buffer of `char`, I'm thinking of using `std::vector` as the backer buffer. What I have in my mind for now is

- obtain the size required by the C API
- create a vector and reserve its size accordingly
- feed the vector to the C API
- get the number of bytes written by the C API
- resize the vector accordingly

The following code outlines the idea:

```cpp
int main(){
  auto required_size = get_required_buffer_size();

  auto buffer = std::vector<char>{};
  buffer.resize(required_size);

  auto read_size = read_data(std::data(buffer), buffer.capacity());
  buffer.resize(read_size);
}
```

Is this a correct usage of `std::vector`, or am I shooting myself in the foot somewhere?

Edit: Change `reserve` to `resize` since the last `resize` will overwrite data written by `read_data`

Comment: Why not call `buffer.resize(required_size);` straight away instead of doing one `reserve` and one `resize`? In fact I'd expect the code as is to overwrite the contents of `buffer` due to that call of `resize` *after*  reading the data

Comment: because `read_data` may return less bytes than `required_size`

Comment: I see, the `resize` in my code my overwrites the contents written by `read_data`, I should do `resize` instead of `reserve`, and then the 2nd `resize` to shrink it back to the actual number of bytes read.

Comment: @UyHà The common way is to `resize()` to the required size before reading **and** `resize()` to the number of bytes actually read _after_ reading. Using `reserve` and writing out of bounds (>= `size()`) makes your program have undefined behavior.

Comment: I'd do the same thing ad OP: calling `resize()` before filling with actual data feels unnecessary (unless you want to initialize the buffer content), and I'd prefer to have `size()` indicating the read data.

Comment: @MatG You'd have UB and in at least g++ and clang++ you wouldn't be able to see the data you read if you `resize()` upwards.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Can you explain what would cause the UB (`reserve()`, write in buffer, then `resize()`), I'm checking my codebase right now if I'm doing that somewhere!

Comment: @MatG Writing in the buffer at positions `>= size()` is UB even if you've reserved space enough.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I naively assumed there would be no risk in case `T` was a fundamental type, but I was wrong (however  luckily I checked I've never done that, I always opted for a very simple custom class `DynamicBuffer<>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is very close, but it could use some subtle changes:

```
auto buffer = std::vector<char>{};
buffer.resize(required_size);
```

can be reduced to

```
std::vector<char> buffer(required_size);
```

And `buffer.capacity()` needs to be either `required_size` or `buffer.size()`.

```
int main(){
  auto required_size = get_required_buffer_size();

  std::vector<char> buffer(required_size);

  auto read_size = read_data(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
  buffer.resize(read_size);
}
```

That being said, in cases where `char[]` buffers are needed, I prefer to use `std::string` instead:

```
int main(){
  auto required_size = get_required_buffer_size();

  std::string buffer(required_size, '\0');

  auto read_size = read_data(buffer.data()/*or: &buffer[0]*/, buffer.size());
  buffer.resize(read_size);
}
```

Comment: the buffer is used as more like raw byte buffer instead of a real string, that's why i prefer `std::vector` to `std::string`

Comment: Raw bytes should be represented using `unsigned char` or `std::byte`

Comment: it’s not what the C API wants though

Comment: Nothing stops you from casting an `unsigned char*` pointer to `char*` when passing it to the C API.

Comment: yes, but that’s just more cumbersome and i don’t really see an advantage to it